# How do I count how many distinct values a row possess?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Suppose I'm given a database of paper routes.

```
Create table routes(route_number varchar(100), route_length varchar(1000)
Create table deliverers(deliv_name varchar(100))
Create table deliveries(Deliv_name varchar(100), route_number varchar(100), 
                        number_of_papers varchar(100), date_of delivery date(yyyy-mm-dd))
```

(i know this isn't complete but we dont need to know the keys for this example)

I want to know the number of routes that each deliverer has, not the amount of deliveries that have taken place on each route. if delivery boy A has 3 routes and he delivers on this route 100 times a year, i only want to know how many routes he has.

I think i need to use set theory or an outer join but im unable to solve this problem so far.

Comment: add  proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT deliverers.deliv_name As DeliveryPerson, COUNT(DISTINCT route_number) As RoutesCount
FROM deliverers 
INNER JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.Deliv_name =  deliverers.deliv_name
GROUP BY (deliverers.deliv_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT      A.deliv_name, COUNT(DISTINCT route_number) AS "NoOfRoutes"
FROM        dbo.deliverers A 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.deliveries B 
                ON A.deliv_name = B.Deliv_name
GROUP BY    A.deliv_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions can use DISTINCT to aggregate only distinct values:

```
SELECT deliv_name,
       count(DISTINCT route_number) AS routes
FROM deliveries
GROUP BY deliv_name;
```

But if you want to include deliverers that have not yet many any delivieries, you have to look into the `deliverers` table, too. This can be done either with an [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join):

```
SELECT deliv_name,
       count(DISTINCT route_number)
FROM      deliverers
LEFT JOIN deliveries USING (deliv_name)
GROUP BY deliv_name;
```

or a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT deliv_name,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT route_number)
        FROM deliveries
        WHERE deliv_name = deliverers.deliv_name
       ) AS routes
FROM deliverers;
```